# what does pygame mean when it says missing required argument 'dest' (pos 2)?

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I'm fairly new to Python but I've been trying to learn to use the Pygame module and every time I try to run my code I get the error message *TypeError:function missing required argument 'dest' (pos 2).* I was trying to get my code to show an image of a character if they were happy (so it'd look like they were smiling). If anyone could explain what I did wrong it'd be greatly appreciated :)

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("Smiley's Window")

shappy = pygame.image.load("smiley_happy.png")
happy = True

#drawing function
def drawGameWindow():
    if happy:
        win.blit(shappy)
    pygame.display.update()

drawGameWindow()
win.fill((0, 0, 0))

pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell pygame where to put the image (destination).

This is done by a tuple of `x` and `y`, for example `(0, 0)`. To do this call

```
win.blit(shappy, (0, 0))
```

which will result in the image being displayed at `0, 0` (top left corner)

Comment: thank you so much! I can't believe I was missing that :)